# implementing unique id name for each hidden value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I am trying to implement an unique id name for each hidden inputs inside while conditions suppose I have this code

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)):

<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="InitTime(<?php echo $row_id; ?>)">Send</button>

<input type="hidden" id="on" value="<?php echo $row_id; ?>">

endwhile; 

function InitTime(row_id, on) {
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure to execute <?php echo $row_id; ?>");
    var on = $("#on").val();
    if (conf == true) {
        $.post("ajax/initializeTime.php", {
                row_id: row_id,
                on:on
             }
        );
    }
}
```

But each time I click the button I get the first row ID from DB but it suppose to be different ID which is comes from DB

And in my initializeTime.php I retrieve same ID

```
if(isset($_POST['row_id']) AND isset($_POST['on']) )
{
     //Here I retrieve the first ID from DB 
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the hidden input? You're already passing the `row_id` to your function

Comment: @billyonecan I have different value on my $on row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have multiple id *on*. ID should be **unique**.

You can so something like:

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)):

<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="InitTime(<?php echo $row_id; ?>)">Send</button>

<input type="hidden" id="on<?php echo $row_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $row_id; ?>">

endwhile;
```

The `id` should now be `on1`, `on2` and so on..

On your js:

```
function InitTime(row_id) {
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure to execute " + row_id +"?");
    var on = $("#on" + row_id).val();
    if (conf == true) {
        $.post("ajax/initializeTime.php", {
                row_id: row_id,
                on:on
             }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: and then how to retrieve the specific ID on another script ?

Comment: IMO best bactice here would be to use a `name` instead of `id` for the inputs and creating a post array.

Comment: @Amanda, what other script? You mean, on php? It will be the same since the ajax code is the same.

Comment: @eisbehr i have tried like <input type="hidden"   name="on[<?php echo $on; ?>]" value="<?php echo $arduino_on; ?>"> but with no success

Comment: @Eddie I have tried your solution but with no success

Comment: Can you check the developer tools if there are errors?

Comment: @Eddie hold on please

Comment: @Eddie as you sad i have now different ID's however on another script again fetching first row

Comment: Is the html being rendered properly? like `<input type="hidden" id="on1" value="1">` `<input type="hidden" id="on2" value="2">`?

Comment: @Eddie yeah exactly id-name + value

Comment: Can you give me an example of rendered input?

Comment: did you update.. `var on = $("#on" + row_id).val();` on `InitTime` function?

Comment: @Eddie var on = $("#on" + row_id).val(); this one I am replacing, and the POSTING in like $on = $_POST['ON']

Comment: @Eddie     var on = $("#on" + <?php echo $arduino_on; ?>).val();
like this

Comment: Nope, you cant do that. It will append only the last id.

Comment: You have to append it on JavaScript variable.

Comment: @Eddie thank you, I resolved my problem with your solution, simply i added var on = $("#on_" + row_id).val();

Comment: Great to hear! Happy to help. :)